# How to bundle an XCode project and deploy onto iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

I have created an iPhone application which I want to deploy onto an iPhone. What is the procedure to deploy it onto the iPhone? Since it's an enterprise application, I've paid the respective amount to Apple to get the certificate. However, I don't know what files to deploy, or how to make my full application as a single bundle. How can I do these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy your application onto your device you will need to install the appropriate provisioning profiles and certificates on your device and computer.

First off:

- Add your device to the provisioning portal
- Create a APP Id in the same portal
- Download the WWDR certificate and install it
- Generate a cerificate for your computer (follow the instructions in the portal)
- Create a provisioning profile in the same portal

Set the correct bundle identifier (e.g. com.mycompany.myapp) in your myapp-Info.plist file.

In XCode, open the project settings and find the row "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY", choose the correct provisioning profile here. Make sure you do it for the correct configuration (e.g. Debug).

I think thats it, don't think there is anything more to do.
This process is quite tricky and bumpy, so good luck! ;)

Comment: What is provisining portal?Can i get the link to download the WWDR certificate?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action
The WWDR file you find under "certificates".

Comment: Hi Paul.. how to unreveal the code .. can we hide the code ? like how we have .exe in Windows... if we place the .exe file and run it runs.. similarly how to do it in MAC/

Comment: Please, RTFM about iOS distribution process.

Comment: @suse if you mean to lock the package so its contents cannot be revealed, I don't think you can. The original source code is not backwards compilable so that you won't have to worry about. But images ect. in the package will be available by reading its content. You can encrypt them though, but thats something else.